# Does YouTube Data API Client Library for Java implement optimize traffic using etags or gzip?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Does the [YouTube Data API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/) use Etags and/or gzip, as described at [Getting started page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags)?

Documentation is short (only find java docs) and don't say anything about it, so i guess is just a wrapper.

Comment: get an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354740/5832311), Etags are supported by youtube but it depends on what kind of data you are asking.

> To use the etag, create a header request and put "If-None-Match" equal to your etag value. Note this should be a request header and not appended to the endpoint call. You can also use "If-Match".

Depending on what kind of API you are using, the way of inserting a new value to the request header may differ slightly. The [ETag](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) response-header field provides the current value of the entity tag for the requested variant.

You may also check on this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752421/youtube-api-v3-and-etag).

Comment: I know the api supports it, the question is if the client library implement it in some way.